# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Hi I am developing an Windows desktop application in C# 4.0, Visual Studio 2010. I have below method to retrieve data from a oracle table.

```
private static MemoryStream GetStatement(OracleConnection con, int loginId, string session, string ip, string acNo, string frmDate, string toDate)
{
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var oraQuery =new OracleCommand(@"SELECT statement_file from
user_account_statement where login_id=" + loginId +" and session_key='" 
+ session + "' and ipaddress='" + ip + "' and account_number='"
+ acNo + "' and from_date=" + frmDate + " and to_date=" 
+ toDate + " and status='closed'", con))
{
using (var oraQueryResult = oraQuery.ExecuteReader())
if (oraQueryResult != null)
{
while (oraQueryResult.Read())
{
var blob = new Byte[(oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
//updated.
memoryStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
}
}
}
return memoryStream;
}
```

while executing the method at query I am getting error that `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.
I tried to suffix `;` to the query but getting the same error.
Could any one correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Bad, bad, very bad...please use parameters instead concatenating string.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. What is your `oraQuery` looks like when you debug your code? Is this commands works on your database manager? (I don't think so, of course)

Comment: What is actual formatted query you executing in command? Add breakpoint, look at oraQuery, copy query to oracle developer and try to execute it.

Comment: I think the problem is with dates: and from_date=" + frmDate + " and to_date=" + toDate - you don't use quotes so these fields are not strings, but your sql string is becoming wrong.

Comment: regarding to date fields in oracle query, i'm also not quite sure if you have to use to_date(...) inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me using parametrized query. Thank you all:

```
private static MemoryStream GetStatement(OracleConnection con, int loginId, string session, string ip, string acNo, DateTime frmDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (
            var oraQuery =
                new OracleCommand(
                    @"SELECT statement_file from user_account_statement where login_id=:1 and session_key=:2" +
                        "and ipaddress=:3 and account_number=:4 and from_date=:5 and to_date=:6" +
                        " and status='closed'", con))
        {
            oraQuery.BindByName = true;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":1", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = loginId;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":2", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = session;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":3", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = ip;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":4", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = acNo;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":5", OracleDbType.Date).Value = frmDate;
            oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":6", OracleDbType.Date).Value = toDate;

            using (var oraQueryResult = oraQuery.ExecuteReader())
                if (oraQueryResult != null)
                {
                    while (oraQueryResult.Read())
                    {
                        var blob = new Byte[(oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                        oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                        memoryStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    }
                }
        }
        return memoryStream;
    }
```